# Get row height of a CListCtrl in MFC

Tags: c++, mfc, clistctrl

I want to resize my `CListCtrl` as `Report` for displaying only n rows with text or empty. And I need the height of a row (they all are of the same size and constant).

```
CRect rect;
myList.GetWindowRect(&rect);
ScreenToClient(&rect);
myList.MoveWindow(rect.left, rect.top, rect.Width(), 16*8-5 /* TODO */);
```

Comment: Is either [GetItemSpacing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb398237(v=vs.90).aspx) or [GetItemRect](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kt4by313(v=vs.90).aspx) useful?

Comment: @Roger: `GetItemRect` does not work for empty list, but `GetItemSpacing` is what I wanted. Thanks!

Comment: @RogerRowland: You should transform you comment on an answer!

Answer (score 0):

CListCtrl with Variable Row Height

```
/*
1a. Setup a typical CListCtrl with owner draw
1b. Fill the CListCtrl with the text you want, as you would normally
2. Setup a CListBox with OwnerDrawVariable and NO border
3. Make the ListBox a child of the ListCtrl
4. Use OnSize to position and OnDrawItem to display the text
Note the OnDrawItem is using the text and some parameters from the CListCtrl
so be mindful of m_lbTest vs. m_lcTest.
*/

void CTestDlg::FillListCtrl()
{
// fill CListCtrl with some text
int x,y;
int ColCount;
CString csStr;

    m_lbTest.SetParent(&m_lcTest);
    ColCount=m_lcTest.GetHeaderCtrl()->GetItemCount();
    for (y=0; y<10; y++) {
        m_lcTest.InsertItem(y,"");
        for (x=0; x<ColCount; x++) {
            csStr.Format("y=%d x=%d",y,x);
            m_lcTest.SetItemText(y,x,csStr);
        }

        m_lbTest.AddString("");
        m_lbTest.SetItemHeight(y,20 + y*10);
    }
}



void CTestDlg::OnSize(UINT nType, int cx, int cy)
{
int x,y;
CRect rb;

    if (m_lcTest.m_hWnd != NULL) {
        y=0;
        x=0;

        m_lcTest.SetWindowPos(&wndTop,x,y,cx,cy-y,SWP_NOZORDER);
        m_lcTest.GetHeaderCtrl()->GetClientRect(&rb);
        x=0;
        y+=rb.Height();
        m_lbTest.SetWindowPos(&wndTop,x,rb.Height(),cx-x-4,cy-y-4,SWP_NOZORDER);
    }
}


void CTestDlg::OnDrawItem(int nIDCtl, LPDRAWITEMSTRUCT lpD)
{
CString csStr;
CRect rc;
CRect rb;
UINT fmt;
LVCOLUMN lvc;
int x,y;
CDC dc;
int ColCount;
CPen cPen;

    CopyRect(&rc,&lpD->rcItem);
    dc.Attach(lpD->hDC);
    dc.SetBkMode(TRANSPARENT);
    dc.SelectObject(GetStockObject(DEFAULT_GUI_FONT));
    cPen.CreatecPen.CreatePen(PS_SOLID,1,RGB(192,192,192));
     dc.SelectObject(cPen);
    dc.SetTextColor(RGB(0,0,0));

    if (m_lbTest.m_hWnd!=NULL && nIDCtl==IDC_LB_TEST) {
         y=lpD->itemID;
        if (y >= 0) {
             rc.left+=5;
            ColCount=m_lcTest.GetHeaderCtrl()->GetItemCount();
             for (x=0; x<ColCount; x++){
                 rc.right=rc.left + m_lcTest.GetColumnWidth(x) - 10;

                 rb.top   =rc.top+1;
                 rb.bottom=rc.bottom;
                 rb.left     =rc.left - 5;
                 rb.right =rc.right + 4;

                if ((lpD->itemState&ODS_SELECTED) != 0) dc.FillSolidRect(&rb,RGB(255,255,192)); // light yellow
                else                    dc.FillSolidRect(&rb,RGB(255,255,255));

                 rb.top--;
                 dc.MoveTo(rb.left-1,rb.bottom);
                 dc.LineTo(rb.right, rb.bottom);
                 dc.LineTo(rb.right, rb.top);
                 dc.LineTo(rb.left-1,rb.top);

                 lvc.mask=LVCF_FMT;
                 m_lcTest.GetColumn(x,&lvc);
                 if      ((lvc.fmt&LVCFMT_RIGHT)  != 0) fmt=DT_RIGHT;
                 else if ((lvc.fmt&LVCFMT_CENTER) != 0) fmt=DT_CENTER;
                 else                                   fmt=DT_LEFT;
                 fmt|=DT_VCENTER | DT_SINGLELINE | DT_END_ELLIPSIS | DT_NOPREFIX;

                csStr=m_lcTest.GetItemText(y,x);
                dc.DrawText(csStr,&rc,fmt);

                 rc.left=rc.right + 10;
            }
        }
    }

    cPen.DeleteObject();
    dc.Detach();
}
```